# calculating keyboard height without using NSNotification in swift

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I have a very small question - can we calculate the Keyboard Height with out using Notification. All the answers in stake overflow is using NSNotification but is there simpler way of calculating it?

below is the code:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification:  ) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            let kbHeight = keyboardSize.height

            }
        }
    }
```

Code to use keyboard height in textFieldDidBeginEditing:

```
var kbHeight: CGFloat?


@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            kbHeight = keyboardSize.height

            }
        }
    }


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if textField.frame.maxY > self.kbHeight!
    {
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: textField.frame.maxY - (self.kbHeight! + 2.0)), animated: true)

    }

    else{
        return
    }

    print(textField.frame.maxY)
    print(self.view.frame.height * 0.6)
    print(textField.frame.maxY - self.view.frame.height * 0.6)

}



func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)

self.view.endEditing(true);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use NotificationCenter?

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I wan to use keyboard height variable in textFieldDidBeginEditing hence want to know if I can get height without notification. I tried to code the logic using notification for calculating height and then use it in textFeidDidBeginEditing but NO LUCK


I have pasted my above for your reference, any help would appreciated

Comment: The reason we use notification center is the keyboard height changes according to keyboard type provided to textfield, textView etc. Hence it provide the size of keyboard accodingly.

Answer (score -2):

actually i don't have any idea for getting keyboard hight directly.. but you can save the keyboard height in variable when keyboard is present and use them where you want

Use these two Observers for keyboard and manage the keyboard hight

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Must be remove these observer at dinit method when pop or dismiss the view controller.

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

Selector methods for keyboard notification ...

```
 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var keyBoardHeight: CGFloat = 0
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        keyBoardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
}
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh, keyboardWillHide and deinit is no longer required and var keyBoardHeight: CGFloat = 0 needs to be defined outside keyboardWillShow. This is almost the same code I wrote .. the problem is var keyBoardHeight is not updating with keyboard height

Comment: Ok, I think you need the keyboard height when keyboard height is changed , if i am understand your problem then solution is:-
use the UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame Observer notification.

Comment: I want to calculate height of keyboard and use it in the textFieldDidBeginEditing .. for weird reason textFieldDidBeginEditing called before notification and hence I could get the keyboard height 

 I believe NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow is right way of doing it as it will calculate the hight of keyboard before editing 

... I have idea what is going wrong here

Comment: first off all textFieldDidBeginEditing is not call before the notification, textViewShouldBeginEditing are called before the notification. and Please tried to add notifications in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.